# Is the Depth buffer in OpenGL the exact Z-values or X^2+Y^2+Z^2?

Tags: opengl, geometry, depth-buffer

What is the **depth-buffer** content in OpenGL related to?
Are they the **Z**-values or the actual depth values from the eye (i.e **sqrt(X<sup>2</sup>+Y<sup>2</sup>+Z<sup>2</sup>)**)?

Comment: that depends on how you render, for fixed function with perspective it is Z coordinate of pixel in camera space after the perspective division and normalization to <-1,+1>. search for Z-buffer or Depth buffer linearisation for more info ...

Comment: I have to add "after the perspective division and normalization to <-1,+1>" AND after converting to [0,1] (see `glDepthRange`). Note that the values in the depth buffer are nonlinear providing a finer resolution the nearer to the camera. Since this nonlinear behaviour is not always wanted, there are several tutorials on howto linearize the values as Spektre said.

Comment: You also skipped clip-space in your explanation. "Camera space" depth in the fixed-function pipeline often does not even have the same direction along the Z-axis because the projection matrix flips it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The depth buffer in OpenGL stores the *window-space* `z` value for each pixel.

Window-space depth is very different from eye-space depth. To get from eye-space to window-space you have to apply projection, perspective division and viewport transformation.

The last detail is probably the most important. After projection and perspective division, the visible range of depths in your viewing volume is [**-1.0**, **1.0**]. The *default* depth range biases and scales those coordinates to the range [**0.0**, **1.0**] and that is what the depth buffer stores.

---

What you described as *"the actual depth values"* is the Euclidean distance in 3D space. That is not usually what people are discussing when they talk about depth. Depth is a measure of distance along the Z-axis.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I forgot that!